# Transit Through Brazil and Panama

Tags: transit, transit-visas, pakistani-citizens, brazil, panama

I'm a Pakistani citizen, willing to travel from KHI (Pakistan) to KIN (Jamaica) on Emirates airline.
Via
kHI 》 DXB 》GRU 》 PTY 》 KIN

emirates do have a code sharing agreement with Copa Air so I believe I will receive 4 boarding passes at my origin.

Do I need Brazilian or Panama visa to transit through these countries?

It will be a one way journey and I have the destination country work visa.

Comment: You can check on the IATA website by entering your full details and travel itinerary here https://www.iatatravelcentre.com/

Answer (score 3):

Regarding Brazil: Brazil only has "regular" visas, not transit visas. If you need one it will depend if the leg DXB->GRU->PTY is a single ticket or not.

If it is a single ticket, and you do not leave the international transit area, then Brazil *does not* require a visa for any nationality ([2017 migraton law](https://portaldeimigracao.mj.gov.br/images/Legisla%C3%A7%C3%A3o_Migrat%C3%B3ria_Compilada/2021_12_20_Compilado_rev_atu.pdf), art. 13, §3).

But if you have multiple tickets for this leg, or if you need to leave the international area to obtain a new boarding pass, then you as a Pakistani *must* have a visitor visa.