# Does an Indian citizen need a transit visa at GRU airport?

Tags: indian-citizens, transit-visas, brazil

I am an Indian passport holder.

I have a flight from Montevideo (MVD) to Bengaluru (BLR) with
change of airport in GRU Sao Paulo on 22nd November '23 and returning back
from Bengaluru (BLR) to Montevideo (MVD) with a change in airport in
GRU Sao Paulo on 1st February '24. (Flight details given below)

Do I need any transit/tourist visa for this travel?

MY ROUTE FROM MONTEVIDEO TO BENGALURU ON 22ND NOVEMBER '23

1. MVD - GRU SAO PAULO (GRU)
2. GRU SAO PAULO (GRU) - ADD ADDIS ABABA
3. ADD ADDIS ABABA - BENGALURU (BLR)

MY ROUTE FROM BENGALURU TO MONTEVIDEO ON 1ST FEBRUARY '24

1. BENGALURU (BLR) - ADD ADDIS ABABA
2. ADD ADDIS ABABA - GRU SAO PAULO (GRU)
3. GRU SAO PAULO (GRU) - MVD

Comment: Is this a single itinerary or have you booked separate flights (for within each part of the trip).

Answer (score 2):

Brazil doesn't have transit visas. If you have a single ticket then you don't need any visa, but if you have multiple tickets then you do need a regular tourist visa. For more details, look [at this answer](https://travel.stackexchange.com/a/180204/122864) to a similar question made by a Pakistani national (Brazil has the same visa policy for both countries).